# Spring data Couchbase generated query method not thread safe

Tags: multithreading, couchbase, sql++, spring-data-couchbase

When i extend CouchbaseRepository interface in order to do a findByField exp findByProvider --> **the method generated is not thread safe** :

My interface :

```
public interface WarehouseRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<WarehouseEntity, String> {

    List<WarehouseEntity> findByProvider(String provider);

}
```

I created a pool of thread in order to test it :

```
int threads = 3;
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);
Collection<Future<Boolean>> futures = new ArrayList<>(threads);
for (int thread = 0; thread < threads; ++thread) {
    String provider ="P1";
    if(thread == 0)
        provider =  "P1";
    if (thread == 1)
        provider =  "P2";
    if(thread == 2)
        provider =  "P3";
    String expectedProvider = provider;
    Callable<Boolean> booleanSupplier = () -> {
        String foundProvider = warehouseService.findByProvider(expectedProvider).get(0).getProvider().toString();
        System.out.println("expectedProvider = " + expectedProvider  + " foundProvider = " + foundProvider);
        return expectedProvider.equals(foundProvider);//should never get false
    };

    futures.add(service.submit(booleanSupplier));
}
Set<Boolean> foundProviders = new HashSet<>();
for (Future<Boolean> future: futures) {
    foundProviders.add(future.get());
}
if (1 != foundProviders.size()) {
    System.out.println("got bad provider response for my query");
}
```

Here is a result of one of my executions :

```
2019/07/03 13:30:39.056 DEBUG Executing N1QL query: {\"args\":[\"P1\"],\"statement\":\"SELECT META(`oms`).id AS _ID, META(`oms`).cas AS _CAS, `oms`.* FROM `oms` WHERE (`provider` = $1) AND `_class` = \\"com.cmt.WarehouseEntity\\"\",\"scan_consistency\":\"statement_plus\"}
2019/07/03 13:30:39.058 DEBUG Executing N1QL query: {\"args\":[\"P3\"],\"statement\":\"SELECT META(`oms`).id AS _ID, META(`oms`).cas AS _CAS, `oms`.* FROM `oms` WHERE (`provider` = $1) AND `_class` = \\"com.cmt.WarehouseEntity\\"\",\"scan_consistency\":\"statement_plus\"}
2019/07/03 13:30:39.056 DEBUG Executing N1QL query: {\"args\":[\"P1\"],\"statement\":\"SELECT META(`oms`).id AS _ID, META(`oms`).cas AS _CAS, `oms`.* FROM `oms` WHERE (`provider` = $1) AND `_class` = \\"com.cmt.WarehouseEntity\\"\",\"scan_consistency\":\"statement_plus\"}
expectedProvider = P2 foundProvider = P1
expectedProvider = P3 foundProvider = P3
expectedProvider = P1 foundProvider = P1
got bad provider for my query
```

For the query in the first line **expectedProvider = P2 foundProvider = P1** we get result of warehousee p1 for a query to find warehouse p2

But when i add @Query to my method, **it becomes by magic thread safe .**

```
@Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE #{#n1ql.filter} AND $1 = provider")
List<WarehouseEntity> findByProvider(String provider);
```

How it is possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this issue seems to have been introduced by [this change](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-couchbase/commit/c4491dc8b4119bc6917188b0ee95f62ae2a5cedc#diff-118522acf7a77cd9498087427b6e636fR62) in November 2018.

Downgrade your spring-data-couchbase to 3.1.2.RELEASE.

Comment: Welcome to SO! We appreciate your input, but please edit your answer a bit, e.g. by citing what the change did and explaining a bit why it solves the issue.

Comment: That is the change I've done, I downgraded spring data version to make it work. I also linked a commit in their repo which broke thread safety and it explains why 3.1.2 is the last one which works as expected. I am not entirely sure what your expectation is here?